# Консультация по производительности. Выборка из БД списка городов, регионов, стран в JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, json, java-ee

На js не так давно начал программировать. Подскажите. Осуществляю выборку стран, городов и регионов из БД MySQL. С помощью скриплетов записываю их напрямую в js код. (JSF не хочу использовать. Странный немного. Лично для меня не понятен.). Казалось бы что все отрабатывает на окей, но возникает вопрос по производительности. Что же все таки лучше. Писать напрямую в JS или использовать AJAX.
Плюсы Ajax в данном случае:
- более упрощенная выборка из бд, меньше потеть по поводу кода
минусы:
- постоянное подключение к бд для обновления списка регионов и городов

Плюсы записи напрямую из БД в js код:
 - при выборе страны, региона, города не надо каждый раз обращаться к бд. Все города и регионы записанны в переменные. Остается лишь только достать их с помощью функции. Т.е. при отправке сервлета пользователю, бд записывает в js весь этот список и при выборе страны и регионов не надо париться по поводу подключения
Минусы: тьма кода который на первый взгляд весьма не понятен.

вот исходник сервлета:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var listCountryes = [];
            <%! MapLocation mapLocation;%>
            <%
                mapLocation = new MapLocation();
                int numberListRegions = 0;
                int numberMapCountry = 0;
                for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<String>>> entryCountry 
                        : mapLocation.getMapLocation().entrySet()) {
                    //создается массив со странами
                    %> 
                    let mapCountry_<%=numberMapCountry%> = new Map();
                    var listRegions_<%=numberListRegions%> = []; 
                    <%
                    int numberMapRegion = 0;
                    int numberListCity = 0;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entryRegion 
                        : mapLocation.getMapLocation().get(entryCountry.getKey()).entrySet()) {

                        // создаем переменную для листа с городами
                        %>
                        let mapRegions_<%=numberMapCountry%>_<%=numberMapRegion%> = new Map(); 
                        var listCityes_<%=numberListRegions%>_<%=numberListCity%> = [];
                        <% 
                        // пробегаемся по листу с городами, добовляем каждый город в лист
                        for (String city : mapLocation.getMapLocation()
                                            .get(entryCountry.getKey())
                                            .get(entryRegion.getKey())) {
                            %>
                            listCityes_<%=numberListRegions%>_<%=numberListCity%>.push('<%=city%>');
                            <%
                        }
                        // конец пробежки по листу с городами, все добавили
                        %>
                        // добавляем полученный лист в регион мапу
                        // [region, list_cityes]
                        mapRegions_<%=numberMapCountry%>_<%=numberMapRegion%>.set('<%=entryRegion.getKey()%>', listCityes_<%=numberListRegions%>_<%=numberListCity%>); 
                        listRegions_<%=numberListRegions%>.push(mapRegions_<%=numberMapCountry%>_<%=numberMapRegion%>);
                        <% 
                        numberListCity++; 
                        numberMapRegion++;
                    }
                    %>
                    mapCountry_<%=numberMapCountry%>.set('<%=entryCountry.getKey()%>', listRegions_<%=numberListRegions%>);
                    listCountryes.push(mapCountry_<%=numberMapCountry%>);
                    <%
                    numberListRegions++;
                    numberMapCountry++;
                }
            %>

            alert("listCountryes - "+listCountryes);
        </script>
```

На выходе в js получается что-то вроде этого (строк тьма около 6 тысяч):

```
let mapCountry_0 = new Map();
                    var listRegions_0 = []; 

                    mapCountry_0.set('Белоруссия', listRegions_0);
                    listCountryes.push(mapCountry_0);

                    let mapCountry_1 = new Map();
                    var listRegions_1 = []; 

                        let mapRegions_1_0 = new Map(); 
                        var listCityes_1_0 = [];

                            listCityes_1_0.push('Адыгейск');

                            listCityes_1_0.push('Майкоп (Адыгея)');

                        // добавляем полученный лист в регион мапу
                        // [region, list_cityes]
                        mapRegions_1_0.set('Адыгея', listCityes_1_0); 
                        listRegions_1.push(mapRegions_1_0);

                        let mapRegions_1_1 = new Map(); 
                        var listCityes_1_1 = [];

                            listCityes_1_1.push('Акташ');

                            listCityes_1_1.push('Акутиха');

                            listCityes_1_1.push('Алейск');

                            listCityes_1_1.push('Алтайский');

                            listCityes_1_1.push('Баево');

                            listCityes_1_1.push('Барнаул');
```

Вот исходник подключения к БД:

```
public class MapLocation {
    private Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> mapLocation;

    private Connection connection;

    public MapLocation() {
        connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DataBase.getConnection();
            mapLocation = getMapCountry(connection);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MapLocation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connection!=null) connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> getMapCountry(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> mapCountry = null;
        try {

            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.append("SELECT * FROM location_country");
            sql.append(" ORDER BY name_country ASC");

            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql.toString());

            mapCountry =  new LinkedHashMap<>();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String nameCountry = resultSet.getString("name_country");
                mapCountry.put(nameCountry, getMapRegion(nameCountry, connection));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (statement!=null) statement.close();
                if (resultSet!=null) resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return mapCountry;
    }

    private Map<String, List<String>> getMapRegion(String nameCountry, Connection connection) {
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        Map<String, List<String>> mapRegion = null;
        try {
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.append("SELECT * FROM location_region");
            sql.append(" LEFT OUTER JOIN location_country ON location_region.index_country = location_country.id_country");
            sql.append(" WHERE name_country = '"+nameCountry+"'");
            sql.append(" ORDER BY name_region ASC");

            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql.toString());

            mapRegion = new LinkedHashMap<>();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String nameRegion = resultSet.getString("name_region");
                mapRegion.put(nameRegion, getListCity(nameRegion, connection));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (statement!=null) statement.close();
                if (resultSet!=null) resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        return mapRegion;
    }

    private List<String> getListCity(String nameRegion, Connection connection) {
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        List<String> listCityInRegion = null;
        try {
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.append("SELECT * FROM location_city");
            sql.append(" LEFT OUTER JOIN location_region ON location_city.index_region = location_region.id_region");
            sql.append(" WHERE name_region = '"+nameRegion+"'");
            sql.append(" ORDER BY name_city ASC");

            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql.toString());

            listCityInRegion = new LinkedList<>();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                listCityInRegion.add(resultSet.getString("name_city"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (statement!=null) statement.close();
                if (resultSet!=null) resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        return listCityInRegion;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> getMapLocation() {
        return mapLocation;
    }

}
```

Господа, варианты?

Comment: Не знаю насколько полезен совет, но тьму пушей можно заменить простым объявлением массива вида `const c = ['Акташ','Акутиха,...']`

Comment: @Dantessss да, такой вариант неплохой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем пользователю подгружать все города всех стран, если он работает только с Московской областью?

Решение однозначно должно быть на аяксе. И других вариантов просто нет.

Чем вас смущает постоянное подключение к БД (особенно, при наличии пула коннектов), я так и не понял.